# why even bother with DAO layer

Tags: spring, jpa, dao

Currently i'm part of a project (`spring` with `JPA`) that has the following layering:

1. service layer (checks for authorization and delegates actions to
   the manager layer)
2. manager layer - does lots of buisiness logic
   and then calls: `entityManager.save(object)`

As you can see there is no `DAO` layer in this project and as a `DAO` layer fanatic i'm starting to fall in love with this setup instead.

what are the pros \ cons of this setup?

Should we bother with dao?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Separation of concerns` is the word that you should think before falling in love with this approach. In general practice business logic and dao logic should be kept separate as in case if in future you decide to change your database you need not go through every class searching for change the way to access new database but in DAO layer approach you need to change only your DAO layer as business layer remains intact.

Comment: Funny thing is , Now, after a couple of months a new requirement was raised in our product and a DAO layer would of make it a ton more easier to accomplish.